# How to join all values for one dataset column into a comma separated string

Tags: reporting-services

Haven't worked with SSRS in quite a while.

I have a Dataset where I'd like to join all rows for a single column into a comma separated list so that I can use that value as a parameter in passed on an action.

Is there something like  `JOIN(DataSet.Food, ",")` that I can do?

```
[Food]
]Apple
]Bannana
]Potato
```

"Apple,Bannana,Potato"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using `LOOKUPSET()` . Normally this function is for looking up a set of values in a dataset that are filtered by a specific value and returning an array of results.

In this case you don't want to filter the results so we can tell `LOOKUPSET` to match two identical literal values, 1 and  1. This way it will return every value in the scope specified. Once we have our array of values, we can use `JOIN()` to glue them all together...

So the Expression you want will look something like this.

```
=Join(LookupSet(1, 1, Fields!Food.Value, "DataSet"),", ")
```

`"DataSet"` is the **case-sensitive** name of the dataset you want to get values from, it must be surrounded with double quotes as shown.

`Food` is the name of the field (again case sensitive) that you want to return from the dataset.

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick.  Unfortunately I wanted to then pass this value as a parameter to an action but I don't think it was possible so I found another way